# Returning the first object in a django queryset

Tags: django

I want to grab only the first element in the queryset below. But if add **.first()**, it returns an error saying that **'Product' object is not iterable**

```
query = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-created_at')
```

Since this is not iterable, how can I grab the first object without converting to other datatypes like list

Comment: You are probably trying to iterate down the code. Show us the usage of a `query`

Comment: `query = serializers.serialize('json', query)`
`return HttpResponse(query, content_type="application/json")`

Comment: But the function doesn't get to this line of code because it stops whenever it encounters that error

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback, and all the usages of `query`?

Answer (score 1):

```
query = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
```

the query return a queryset and you can select item from this queryset by index

in your case you need get the first item in queryset

so you can select item by index [0] and get the first item

we deleted .order_by('-created_at') because the index get the first item

I hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the following to my answer, The objects are stored in the database in order by 'created at' by default. So we would not need to use created at after the filter.
to grab the first one:

```
query = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
```

to grab the last one:

```
query = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)[-1]
```

I think it would suffice. apart from this try and except method can be used to raise the proper error without crashing the code.